# Change the order of HTML element by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd love to change the order of HTML elements from:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="dd1"></div>
    <table id="t1"></table>
    <div id="be_top"></div>    
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="dd1"></div>
    <div id="be_top"></div>    
    <table id="t1"></table>
</div>
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you refer to the API documentation, you'll find the [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) function:

```
$("#be_top").insertBefore("#t1");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/epalun/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/epalun/1/edit)

Or of course, you could do it the other way around with [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("#t1").insertAfter("#be_top");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/epalun/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/epalun/2/edit)

An hour spent reading the API documentation beginning to end (and it really only takes that long) is hugely rewarding, saving you a lot of time over even just a brief period.

Answer (score 2):

```
// select thing you want to move #be_top -> insert it before #t1
$("#be_top").insertBefore("#t1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can use *appendTo* also in JQuery.

Ex :

```
var nav = $('#t1').clone(true);
$('#t1').remove();
nav.appendTo('#be_top');
```